# I'm looking for ideas to audit logon/logoff

Tags: powershell

I dont have any code yet.

I'm wanting a script to run on servers that will write to a file everytime a user logs and then again when they logoff. I dont really have any ideas other than how to distribute a script. What ever script I come up with or find GPO logon and logoff action might be the easiest. What are some other ideas.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Like I stated in my question I havent tried anything not really sure where to start. I'm looking for ways to accomplish this.

Comment: You really need to do your homework (research) first. There are several ways that this kind of thing can be done; you need to judge which of those ways fits your needs and your environment. Some effort with Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, et cetera, can probably give you not only the available methods, but useful explanations of the advantages and disadvantages of each, and possibly even sample code or other instructions.

Comment: Sorry you felt my question was too general Jeff and that it was such a bother to you. Honestly I just wanted to get a couple ideas to look into further. Google is always my first stop.

Comment: If you don't discuss your research/findings, we don't know (a) what your level of understanding of the problem is; (b) whether you've found and rejected one or more options; (c) what the context of your question is, which may affect the responses that you get. This is why I posted my original comment, with the links to MCVE and Good Question.

Comment: Thanks Jeff but Connor helped me with an idea and now I will see if I can expand on or find another route. I understand your point no need to keep making sure I know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to accomplish it via scripting then you can add a shortcut to launch a script which just does `"$($env:USERNAME);$(Get-Date)" | Out-File "C:\log.txt" -Append` to the startup directory.

if you're looking for other methods of windows auditing (more secure and reliable than a script in the startup dir), you can look at enabling `account logon auditing` and find the related event IDs by checking out a [few](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976367.aspx) - [articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc431373.aspx) on the subject, when you enable it via group policy the event log will have events for any subsequent logons the DC handles, so any critical servers which use AD authentication can be tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Connor